# A line in a proof regarding nth power residues

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I would appreciate help understanding this highlighted line in a proof in Ireland & Rosen (p. 45). I don't know much group theory although I know the residue classes $\pmod m$ form a multiplicative group whose order is $\phi(m)$.

Prop 4.2.1: If $m\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and $(a,m)=1$ then $a$ is an $n$th power residue iff $a^{\phi(m)/d} \equiv 1\pmod m$ where $d= (n,\phi(m))$:

In the proof it says: If $g$ is a primitive root $\pmod m$ and $a=g^b$ and $x=g^y$ then $x^n\equiv a\pmod m$ is equivalent to $g^{ny} \equiv g^b\pmod m$ (so far so good) which is equivalent to:

> > If $g^{ny}\equiv g^b \pmod m$ then $ny\equiv b\pmod {\phi(m)}$

Thanks

**EDIT** Due to my carelessness, I left out a crucial part of the statement of the Proposition. It should be "if $m$ possesses primitive roots, etc" I left my misstatement above as it stands since it resulted in the illuminating answer from @Daniel Fischer below.

Comment: Hmm, let $m = 15 = 3\cdot 5$ and $n = 4$. Then $\phi(m) = \phi(3)\cdot \phi(5) = 2\cdot 4 = 8$, so $d = (n,\phi(m)) = (4,8) = 4$, and the assertion is that $a$ (of which we assume $(a,m) = 1$) is a biquadratic residue modulo $15$ if and only if $a^{8/4} = a^2 \equiv 1 \mod{15}$. But for $b$ coprime to $15$, we have $b^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{15}$, so $1$ is the only biquadratic residue modulo $15$, while $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{15}$ has the solutions $1,4,11,14 \pmod{15}$.

Comment: In the proof, a primitive root $\pmod{m}$ is mentioned, but a primitive root $\pmod{m}$ only exists if $m$ is $2,4$, a power of and odd prime, or twice a power of an odd prime. Is there such a restriction on $m$ mentioned in the proposition?

Comment: @DanielFischer I quoted the Prop verbatim

Comment: In that case, we've found a mistake in the book, it seems.

Comment: @DanielFischer Well thanks for the "we," but in truth it's all you. Regards,

Comment: I didn't look at the highlighted bit before. It ought to read "… then $ny \equiv b \pmod{\phi(m)}$", not $gy$. Don't know if that's your typo or Ireland & Rosen's. Anyway, $g^{ny} \equiv g^b \pmod{m} \iff g^{ny-b} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$. And if $g$ is a primitive root, then $g^k \equiv 1 \pmod{m} \iff \phi(m) \mid k$. We can express the latter as $k \equiv 0 \pmod{\phi(m)}$. And with $k = ny-b$, we have $ny-b \equiv 0 \pmod{\phi(m)} \iff ny \equiv b \pmod{\phi(m)}$. See above for when a primitive root exists.

Comment: @DanielFischer My error, ugh

Comment: @DanielFischer Maybe you would please past your comment to an answer so I can accept it. Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: Here, primitive root and generator are the same. Generally, the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/(m)$ is not cyclic. But you can write it as a direct product of cyclic groups, and look at the factors separately. Instead of Euler's totient function, in the general case one needs the Carmichael function (the smallest exponent of the group). The correct condition is that $a^{\lambda(m)/d} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$, where $d = (n,\lambda(m))$ and $\lambda$ is the Carmichael function.

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, the condition is only correct when there exists a primitive root modulo $m$, i.e. when the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/(m)$ is cyclic. In that case, the highlighted line holds because we have $g^{ny} \equiv g^b \pmod{m} \iff g^{ny-b} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$, and $g^k \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$ if and only if $k$ is a multiple of the order of $g$. By definition, a primitive root modulo $m$ has order $\phi(m)$, so $g^k \equiv 1 \pmod{m} \iff \phi(m) \mid k$, and $\phi(m) \mid k$ is the definition of $k \equiv 0 \pmod{\phi(m)}$. So

\begin{align}
g^{ny} \equiv g^b \pmod{m} &\iff g^{ny-b} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}\\
&\iff ny -b \equiv 0 \pmod{\phi(m)}\\
&\iff ny \equiv b \pmod{\phi(m)}.
\end{align}

As an example that the condition as written does not hold for all $m$, take $m = 15$ and $n = 4$. Then $\phi(m) = 8$, and $d = (n,\phi(m)) = 4$, so the condition is $a^{8/4} = a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{15}$, but this congruence is satisfied by $1,4,11,14 \pmod{15}$, while $b^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{15}$ for all $b$ coprime to $15$, so the only biquadratic residue modulo $15$ is $1$.

For general $m$, we must replace Euler's totient function $\phi$ with the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) $\lambda$. For $a$ coprime to $m$, and $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, $a$ is an $n^{\text{th}}$-power residue if and only if $a^{\lambda(m)/d} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$, where $d = \gcd(n,\lambda(m))$. The proof is similar to the proof when the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/(m)$ is cyclic, one writes the unit group as a product of cyclic groups and argues in each factor in the given way.

Comment: Dear Daniel - Please accept my apologies for my inexcusable carelessness (see EDIT) and any extra work it may have caused you. Although your answer was all the more illuminating. With regards,

Comment: No problem. I'm a slow typist, but it's not much work to type a few lines.

Comment: Hi Daniel - I was wondering if in the last line of the first paragraph it should be $k\equiv 0 \pmod \phi(m)$. And maybe you might want to say $b^4\equiv 1\pmod 15$ consistent with your comment. And lastly, I was wondering if the reason exclusively mention "all coprime to $m$" is because we are assuming $g$ is a generator? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that should have been $k \equiv 0 \pmod{\phi(m)}$, thanks. And using $b$ instead of $a$ there is also better. I'm not sure I understand the last question. When looking at $n$-th power residues, one typically only looks at the remainders coprime to the modulus, because they form a group under multiplication, that's convenient. Generally, one splits $m$ into prime powers, solves the corresponding problem, and combines solutions per the Chinese remainder theorem. When we have a prime power $m = p^r$, and a remainder $a$ with $p \mid a$, the problem is near trivial if $r \leqslant n$.

Comment: For if $a \equiv b^n \pmod{p^r}$ and $p \mid a$, then we must also have $p \mid b$ and hence $b^n \equiv 0 \pmod{p^r}$ when $r \leqslant n$. If $r > n$, things are a bit more complicated. But the consideration before shows that $a \not\equiv 0 \pmod{p^r}$ can only be an $n$-th power residue modulo $p^r$ if $a = \tilde{a}\cdot p^{s\cdot n}$ with $p \nmid \tilde{a}$ and $s \in \mathbb{N}$. Then one checks whether $\tilde{a}$ is an $n$-th power residue modulo $p^{r - s\cdot n}$, so that takes you back to the coprime case.

Comment: That last question was why you specified $b^4\equiv 1\pmod 15$ for *all* $b$ *coprime to* $15$. And I was checking if it was because $b^4$ is supposed to be a power of a generator.

Comment: Ah. Because, like Ireland & Rosen, I was only considering residues coprime to $m$. If the group of units modulo $m$ is not cyclic (as is the case for $m = 15$), we don't have a generator, so we can't write anything as a power of a generator. But when we write the group as a product of cyclic groups (corresponding to the different prime powers dividing $m$; with a small special case for $2$, when $8 \mid m$, then the group of units modulo $2^r$ is a product of two cyclic groups), we can work with a generator in each factor.

Comment: And indeed one reason why one concentrates on residues coprime to $m$ is that one can work with generators, which simplifies things.

Comment: Sorry to take so long to formalize this. My wife was having surgery

Comment: I hope it went well. Please relay her my best wishes for a speedy recovery, @Andrew.

Comment: Thanks for your kind thoughts